# When using Robotium in android for unit testing how to take run time data from server?

Tags: android

I an using Robotium-solo for android unit testing and I want to take data from web-server how can I do this run time and make some test cases for this, like I have data or not. Please help me to solve this out I really stuck in this..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface for class which communicating with server if you haven't it. Create two implemetations of this interface: one real-implementation and another one - stub which return exactly what you need without any real-communications with server. Then in your test case just substitute real implementation by their stub and wrote your test logic